# Сильно тормозит Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, java

Всем привет! У меня такая проблема: при использовании Android Studio сильно тормозит комп. Например, бывает, при наборе текста клавиши уже нажаты, а на экране появляются через несколько секунд, сборка проектов - от 2 до 5 мин. Конфигурация ноут Asus k50in (4гб оперативки, проц dual-core t4400 2.20Ггц, W7).

Есть ли какие-нибудь способы решить эту проблему, а то новый комп покупать не хочется?

Comment: На форуме уже было обсуждение данной темы. Посмотрите подробнее пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно отправить студию в режим экономии энергии. Она отключает автоподстановку, анализ синтаксиса и разные другие возможности.

Answer (score 3):

Сам сижу на таком же ноуте, аналогичная ситуация с тормозами.
В настройках gradle (user/.gradle/gradle.properties) прописывал следующее

> ```
> org.gradle.daemon=true  
> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8   
> org.gradle.parallel=true  
> org.gradle.configureondemand=true
> ```

немного, но помогло. Плюс в настройках студии/idea отключал code complete.
А вообще давно подумываю о смена железа (можно еще ssd прикупить, не уверен только, что будет существенный прирост скорости).   
**edit**: да, еще добавлял папку с проектами в исключение антивируса.

Comment: ssd дает хороший прирост и для студии также. Главное, чтобы студия и java, которую она использует, были на ssd.

Comment: Не буде особого "(можно еще ssd прикупить, не уверен только, что будет существенный прирост скорости). ". Конечно на chrome будет так как он всегда мучает жесткий своими обращениями(а другие браузеры не). А AndroidStudio у нее проблема прожорливости а не проблема с жестким.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй поставь IDEA.
Не ставил студию, но знаю, что она базируется на IDEA, и читал, что тормоза бывают из-за Gradle. По сравнению с Eclipse IDEA просто летает.

По поводу SSD - можно попробовать оценить прирост перемещения студии и JAVA машины на  SSD без покупки SSD с помощью RAMDisk (Диск в оперативке). Одна из программ, позволяющая это сделать, - ImDisk.

Comment: idea тоже тормозит неслабо.

Comment: У меня вообще 1.5 Гб оперативы на ноуте.И Eclipse у меня вообще не лагает и оперативы жрет раза в 2 меньше, чем Android Studio и IDEA

Answer (score 1):

Отключи систему контроля версий, если активно не пользуешься ей. С Android Studio была такая же проблема - настолько невозможно было работать, что на домашнем компьютере пришлось отказаться от неё. После отключения плагинов VCS, Studio стала работать на уровне IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Это 100% из за операционной памяти. Я воткнул в свой комп 16gb и все шикарно заработало. Памяти жрет эта Студия - вот в чем проблема. Хотя бы 8gb поставь..

Comment: У меня 3гб DDR2 800Мгц, AS вполне сносно работает с автоподстановкой, браузером, читалкой и мелкими программами. Даже антивирус включен!

Comment: Я уже на Linux пересел. До этого на Винде с 4GB RAM всё тормозило. Как только поставил 16GB, всё стало работать нормально. Андроид Студия жрёт РАМ если запускать Gradle. Если сразу тестировать на подключённом живом аппарате, то может будет шустрее, я не пробовал.

Comment: Не знаю... У меня, во время компиляции, конечно, подтормаживает, но вообще - все хорошо. Многое от жесткого диска зависит.